# How to define the image, that shows up in streamline when I click the fb-like button?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

So I was wondering how the facebook like button works. I mean whenever you click on the like button, it shows up in your fb-newsfeed with an image. In my case it shows always an image I dont want, the logo of my page.

Is there a way to change that? Hands on example here: http://stories.mysecretathens.gr/montalbano.html

Comment: Install the Open Graph meta tags http://ogp.me